# Казацкий и казачий — есть ли разница?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, морфология, прилагательные

Употребляются слова и "казачий", и "казацкий". Например, есть растение *можжевельник казачий*. Есть *казацкая шашка*, но при этом, например, *казачья станица*. Хотя можно, наверное, сказать и *казацкая станица*.
Тогда почему употребляются сразу две формы прилагательного и, главное, есть ли какое-то смысловое различие между словами "казачий" и "казацкий"?

Answer (score 4):

Здесь можно ответить так. Если стоит вопрос «чья?», то напрашивается ответ *казачья* (например, казачья станица). Если «какая?» — *казацкая* (казацкая шашка). Вопрос можно задать по-разному (и чья, и какая), поэтому разные и ответы.
Ещё примеры: шутка (чья?) — ребячья, но (какая?) — детская. С этим можно спорить, но для себя я так различаю.

Answer (score 2):

У относительного прилагательного "казацкий"  широкий спектр значений: казацкий караул,  казацкий генерал, казацкий офицер, казацкий кафтан, на казацкий лад, казацкий конь. Также слово "казацкий" может заменять слово "казачий".

У притяжательного прилагательного "казачий" значение вполне определенное: относящийся к войскам, состоящим из казаков, а также принадлежащий казакам. К. офицер. К. сотник. К. полк. К-ья сотня. Казачий хор. Казачий сын. Казачий род.

В то же время из различных текстов ясно, что слова часто заменяют друг друга. В этом случае следует учитывать их обобщенное различие: имеющий отношение к казачеству (казацкий)  или внутренне с ним связанный (казачий).

Answer (score 0):

В станице Раздорской на Дону я слышал от казаков следующее. У донский и кубанских казаков все говорят обо всем только "казачий". А у других (например: уральских, сибирских и пр.) говорят и так и так, или только "казацкий".

Comment: Говорят и так, и эдак. Есть ли разница?